# angularjs SPA - how to flush memory?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory

I am using angularjs single page app in my webpage,

following is code for spa constructor

```
app.config(config);
config.$inject = ['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider'];
function config($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider){
    $stateProvider.state('dashboard',{
        url:'/{userID}/{testID}',
        templateUrl:'templates/dashboard.html',
        controller:'dashboardCtrl'      
    });
}
```

template `dashboard.html` displays number of google graphs and charts.
In controller `dashboardCtrl`, I make GET/POST requests to server using `$http` directive, and plot google graphs using response data.

following is code for service (`$http` request)

```
app.service('getGraphData',getGraphData);
getGraphData.$inject = ['$http'];
function getGraphData($http){
    var obj = this;
    obj.getLatestData = function(testID){
        return $http({
            method:'GET',
            url:'/rest/getGraphDataForTestID',
            params:{testID:testID}
        }
        ).then(function(response){
            // success response
            return(response.data);
        });
    }
    return obj;
}
```

controller code -

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl',dashboardCtrl);
dashboardCtrl.$inject = ['$scope','$rootScope','getGraphData','$stateParams'];
function dashboardCtrl($scope,$rootScope,getGraphData,$stateParams){
    var testID = $stateParams.testID;
    var userID = $stateParams.userID;
    var graphData = null;
    getGraphData.getLatestData(testID).then(function(response){
        $scope.testname = response.data.testname;
        $scope.tag = response.data.tag;
        ..
        ..
        $scope.results = response.data;
        graphData = response.data;
        drawBarChart(graphData);
        drawPieChart(graphData);
    });
}
```

I have number of links like following in my index page

```
<a  ui-sref = "dashboard({userID:1,testID:197})"><b>dashboard-userid:1,graphs:197</b></a>
<a  ui-sref = "dashboard({userID:1,testID:198})"><b>dashboard-userid:1,graphs:198</b></a>
```

This setup is working fine for some time, but after some time I get browser error message "**browser ran out of memory to display this webpage**"

Maybe because angularjs is saving previous `$scope` and `$rootScope` variables, and also creating new ones when template is reloaded...
or simply JavaScript variables are not getting deleted...
(but i am not using global variables - all are declared inside controller functions, which should have same life as that function)

How do i clear/flush these `$scope/$rootScope` variables and free memory...
How can i analyse memory usage of my particular page..??
Please help...

Answer (score 0):

There is a chrome extension which lets you analyze you angular apps for performance - [Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk).

It shows `$scope` and `$rootScope` variables as well.